# Protractor script is too fast and elements on overlay are not handled

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, automated-tests

Below is my code in the spec. Toolbox is a library of commonly used operations such as sendKeys(), etc.

```
async enterProjectDetails() {
toolbox.enterText(this.projectTitle, "001 Project Name");
toolbox.enterText(this.projectDescription, "New project");
await toolbox.click(this.someTextBox);
//on clicking this text box an overlay is displayed
//Used the below but none of them worked
// toolbox.waitUntilVisible(this.chkBoxOnOverlay);

// var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  <--- didn't work
// browser.driver.wait(function () {
//  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.chkBoxOnOverlay), 10000);
//  return elem;
// });

//  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  <--- didn't work
// browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("(//li[@class='ng-star-inserted']//mat-checkbox)[1]"))), 5000);


// await toolbox.click(this.chkBoxOnOverlay);
toolbox.click(this.cancel);  <--- cancel on the overlay is also skipped
//MORE CODE ALL OF WHICH ARE EXECUTED BY HIT OR MISS
}
```

Script proceeds to enter values in the text box below the overlay and exits out. The value to be entered on the overlay is a mandatory field and I can't proceed from the page without checking some values.

Is there any way to slow down protractor? All the console.logs are also executed at the same time (from first line of the code to last line.) Is this because of the asynchronous nature of JS? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute them in wanted order using promises like this:

```
toolbox.enterText(this.projectTitle, "001 Project Name").then(function () {
    toolbox.enterText(this.projectDescription, "New project").then(function(){
       toolbox.click(this.someTextBox);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is still not working as the overlay does appear but no element in the overlay is handled. I am not able to slow down the script as browser.sleep is not working and can't debug on VSCode either. :(

Comment: @williamtell if you want the steps to be executed in correct order please use .then(function(){} on every step.